# Do a simple json POST using RESTKit

Tags: objective-c, json, cocoa-touch, post, restkit

I'm new to iOS development and I'm having trouble making a simple Json POST request.
I have a NSDictionary containing an user and password and I want to send those values as a Json to a server and get a response. I had that working without using restkit but I can't figure out how to accomplish the same using RestKit and just can't find a good example of what I want.

```
- (bool) login{

    NSMutableDictionary* params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [params setValue:self.email forKey:@"email"];
    [params setValue:self.password forKey:@"password"];    

    NSMutableDictionary* rpcData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [rpcData setValue:@"2.0" forKey:@"jsonrpc"];
    [rpcData setValue:@"authenticate" forKey:@"method"];
    [rpcData setValue:@"" forKey:@"id"];
    [rpcData setValue:params forKey:@"params"];

    [[RKClient sharedClient] post:@"/api/rpc/" params:rpcData delegate:self];
    return nil;
}
```

The server is expecting a Json like this:

```
{
    jsonrpc : '2.0',
    method : 'authenticate', // method name goes here
    params : {  // params are method-specific
        email : 'test@test.com',
        password : 'secret'
    },
    id : 2  // The id can be anything, it will be sent back with the response
}
```

I understand that there is a Json parser include in RestKit but I can't find any documentation on how to parse my rpcData dictionary, do I need to use an external library?.

Right now the communication with the server it's ok, but I'm not sending what is expected. My dictionary is mapped in the way "key=value?key2=value2...". This is very silly question but I'm stucked.

**Update**

*By the time I wrote this, it worked but Restkit has been updated so I'm not sure if this will work, please check their documentation*

Here is the solution to my problem, what I'm doing is ideal for working with RPC APIs when you need to call a service:

1.- First in your object you need to import Restkit and RKRequestSerialization, this is very important:

```
#import <RestKit/RestKit.h>
#import <RestKit/RKRequestSerialization.h>

@interface myObject : NSObject <RKRequestDelegate,RKObjectLoaderDelegate>
```

2.- Here is the login function sending the post:

```
- (void) login:(NSString *)username :(NSString *)password{

    RKClient *myClient = [RKClient sharedClient];
    NSMutableDictionary *rpcData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init ];
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    //User and password params
    [params setObject:password forKey:@"password"];
    [params setObject:username forKey:@"email"];

    //The server ask me for this format, so I set it here:
    [rpcData setObject:@"2.0" forKey:@"jsonrpc"];
    [rpcData setObject:@"authenticate" forKey:@"method"];
    [rpcData setObject:@"" forKey:@"id"];
    [rpcData setObject:params forKey:@"params"];

    //Parsing rpcData to JSON! 
    id<RKParser> parser = [[RKParserRegistry sharedRegistry] parserForMIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *json = [parser stringFromObject:rpcData error:&error];    

    //If no error we send the post, voila!
    if (!error){
        [[myClient post:@"/" params:[RKRequestSerialization serializationWithData:[json dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] MIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON] delegate:self] send];
    }
}
```

Comment: It isn't clear what the problem is. Is the data not being sent? Not being received? What do your request and response headers look like? Consider using http://www.charlesproxy.com/ to help. And also, don't forget to check the green check mark next to the best answer for your previous questions. You'll get more responses that way.

Comment: In the way my code is, I'm not sending a JSON request. I have that clear, the server is getting data like "?jsonrpc='2.0'&method='authenticate'..." I need to know how to parse that into a JSON

Comment: You can check the request sent by Restkit by activating the debug log via this line in code `RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/Network", RKLogLevelTrace);`

Comment: Also do you have to do the RKParserRegistry thing everytime you want to make a POST request?

Comment: Is just necessary when you need to parse some dictionary to something, in my case JSON. After using Restkit I recommend to use object mapping for this kind of request, it's cleaner because the JSON or any transformation is made when you map the object.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem, and this is what solved it for me.  Note, in my scenario, I only wanted to access RKRequest.

```
NSDictionarty *dict
NSError *error; 
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:0 error:&error];

if (!jsonData) 
{
    NSAssert(FALSE, @"Unable to serialize JSON from NSDict to NSData"); 
} 
else 
{
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    request.params = [RKRequestSerialization serializationWithData:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] MIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];
}
```

The key for me was the 'MIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON' in the last line.  Since I only wanted to use RKRequest, this was how I needed to set the MIME type.  Otherwise, I would use Paul Cezanne's suggestion.

Comment: This is the same that I already put on my question update I think, but it's ok :P

Answer (score 24):

**For older RestKit**

You probably have something like this in your delegate:

```
    objectManager.serializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeFormURLEncoded;
```

You want it to be:

```
    objectManager.serializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;
```

**For RestKit v.20:**

```
    // thanks  ColdLogic (from his comment)
    [objectManager setRequestSerializationMIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];
```

Comment: I'm not working with object Manager, I think that your suggestion works when you map an object. This is not the case but I think I solved my problem. I'll post the solution assap. Thanks Paul!.

Comment: for restkit v.20: `[objectManager setRequestSerializationMIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];`