# How can I insert Data from Iphone to a distant data base in a server ??? (xcode 4.2)

Tags: database, xcode, web-services, insert

I want to insert data from textfield in a view to a distant data base on a server  when I click on a button

and I want to retrieve data from a distant data base and show this data in a label in a view for example

If you have a good and sample tutorial please give me the link 
or give the code to start with because I am a beginner in the world of xcode

Thinks for Advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need a back end server which will take a request that you send it and perform the retrieval from the database. Once the back end server retrieves the data, it then responds back to your client (the app running on the iPhone).

The back end would usually be written in a language such as PHP, C#, Java etc. You will have to look at how to do database calls in the particular language that you will use.

I use RESTKit to perform requests from my client to my back end server and it sends and retrieves data in the JSON (http://json.org/) format. http://restkit.org/

You can see a simple example here: [Do a simple json POST using RESTKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9102262/do-a-simple-json-post-using-restkit)

So it goes App->Back end->Database->Backend->App.

You can't directly access a database straight from your app without a back end.

Comment: thinks Asagohan but Have you an example with the PHP WebServices as the server part !!