# Restkit. Show response body on storyboard

Tags: objective-c, json, restkit, restkit-0.20

I want to show on the storyboard the responde body that i get from the server, im doing the connection [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19632529/simple-json-login-post-on-restkit-0-20).
When i run the app, i get the following response:

```
response.body={"id":2,"token":"xyzzyzzyx"}
2013-11-05 11:36:52.405 networkTest3[1327:70b] It Worked: (
    "<LoginResponse: 0x8b508a0>"
)
```

Im trying to show the data from LoginResponse on masterview, following the CoffeeShop example but it seems many things are different because of the RestKit version (Im using the last one, 0.20 right now). I already know how to connect the data from the class to the Outlets on the interface but i cant find how i get the data from the response body.

Im trying to do it with this method on the class LoginResponse

```
- (void)loadToken{
    RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[LoginResponse class]];

    [mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                  @"id":   @"status",
                                                  @"token":   @"token",
                                                  }];
        RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:mapping pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myurl.com"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
    RKObjectRequestOperation *objectRequestOperation = [[RKObjectRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request responseDescriptors:@[ responseDescriptor ]];

    [objectRequestOperation start];
}
```

And i got this:

```
2013-11-05 12:09:56.867 networkTest3[1585:3307] E restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:576 Object request failed: Underlying HTTP request operation failed with error: (null)
```

What im doing wrong and what would be my next step?

EDIT: I tried to add this on LoginManager.m

```
[responseMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"id" : @"id", @"token" : @"token"}];
```

But i got

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Unable to add mapping for keyPath token, one already exists...'
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set any headers on the results you're making so the server doesn't know how to appropriately respond to the request. With a null error it's impossible to tell more really. Your mapping looks fine and your log shows that the appropriate object is created.

Consider setting at least your `Accepts` header on the request or using an `RKObjectManager` to handle the request management for you.

---

If that isn't a real error and your mapping is working (it looks basically ok), then your issue is that you aren't calling `setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:failure:` so you never get a callback with the objects that were created during the mapping process.

Again, using `RKObjectManager` would make this easier to handle and harder to forget / miss...

Comment: What is `operario_id`? Did you get a key not found exception? Did you set the headers? You need to show full exception details.

Comment: Edit with exception details. Im still looking for a way to add the response body into a list of objects to later show the data on the storyboard. I removed the last thing i added on LoginManager.m and i dont know how to continue because the documentation is old or a little confusing.